# Como ordenar informacion de una tabla HTML

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql

tengo un requerimiento en un trabajo de la U, tengo unos clientes en una base de datos, los cuales debo organizar en una ruta para visitarlos de forma semanal, dicha ruta la determino yo conforme vaya registrando los nuevos clientes, yo los vaya organizando de tal manera que me parezca una ruta cómoda, tengo estos clientes

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

La idea es que queden organizados de cierta forma que a mi me parezca mas fácil ejemplo:
Primero ir al cliente de LA VERDA LOT 4, de ahí ir a LA BASTILLA LOC 3, luego ir a VC VILLA CO, y se me muestre ya sea en una TABLA HTML O en algun otro componente para verlo de forma organizada
Necesito ideas para ver cómo dar con esta solución, una que se me ocurrió es agregar otra columna ala base de datos que se llame ruta, y asignar un numero a cada uno de ellos y así organizarlos desde un Query, pero me gustaría saber si hay alguna otra manera. porque ahora es fácil que hay menos de 10 clientes, pero cuando sean 100 por ejemplo.

La razón de esto es poder ir mirando en una app de arriba hacia abajo los clientes que voy visitando e ir tachándolos para que no me quede faltando alguno, también intente la organización de los datos poniéndolos en una tabla HTML y organizarlos con JavaScript pero una vez se cierra la app nuevamente se des organizan

MUCHAS GRACIAS, TODAS LAS IDEAS SERAN BIENVENIDAS, siguiendo el caso de la tabla que mostre la ruta ideal seria

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Estas rutas pueden ser cambiates porque puede que llegue un cliente que su direccion quede de primera para visitar o de tercera y asi, muchas gracias espero su ayuda

Comment: Hola Osnaider, tu pregunta es demasiado abierta y las respuestas están basadas en opiniones, has intentado hacer algo concreto en código para solucionarlo? Te recomiendo leer [esto](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) para que tu pregunta pueda ser respondida.

Comment: En cuanto al problema que describes, parece que lo tienes bastante claro; el objetivo es listar esos datos en una tabla y proveer un mecanismo al usuario para agregar nuevos datos y ordenarlos manualmente ya que no hay un criterio común que te permita automatizarlo, solo debes comenzar con la implementación e ir paso a paso solucionando las dudas técnicas puntuales en el camino. Es ahí donde te podremos ayudar. Te recomiendo dividir el problema en varias partes y comenzar por lo básico e ir añadiendo funcionalidad incrementalmente.